# Unable to access the classes from a custom swift framwork in iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, frameworks, cocoapods

I have created a swift framework which contains Obj C classes, and I am trying to use it in my demo app (written in obj c) using development Pods (local cocoa pods), I could able to import the Headers, and I could able to call the methods which are in the framework, but I am getting the following error while compiling the demo app

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassName", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I resolve this? any suggestion would be appeciated

Updates: Define Module is set to YES in framework's build settings, Under Packaging

Comment: Probably, you've smthng wrong written in your podfile. Could you paste it here?

Comment: U wanna review pod of podspec file?

Comment: yes, if you didnt solve your problem, yet

Comment: Did you find the solution? If yes please do share.